# Tabular overfill

Tags: tables

This table overfill the margins.  I am working on a document with several tables and in some cases the tables overfill the margin. I have tried mini page but with little success - any suggestions?

```
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{Implied Cost of Funds}
\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{lrrl}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Beginning Market Value}}\\
Principal Proceeds & \$ &1,028,437 & $\text{\$1,000,000} \times \text{\$102-27}$ \\
Accrued Interest & \$ &1,986 & 13 days accrued interest @ 5.50\%\\
\circled{1} \textbf{Market Value} &\$& 1,030,424 & Total proceeds on the "roll out" date \\
\hline

\multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{Future Value} - \textit{Pmts. Received}}\\
Coupon Income Received & \$& 4,583 & Interest earned @ 5.50\%  based on 30/360\\
Scheduled Principal Received & \$ &1,070 & Scheduled principal paid\\
Prepaid Principal Received & \$ & 29,254 & Prepaid Principal Received @ 30 CPR\\
Total Payments Received & \$& 34,907 & Expected payments (remittance date)\\
\circled{2} \textbf{Disc. value of the carry} & \$ & 34,911 & Present value of the payments received\\
&&&assuming the alternate financing rate (0.31\%) \\
&&&and using actual day count (13 days) - act/360 - \\
&&& on the "roll in" date.\\ 

\hline 
Remaining principal balance & \$ & 969,676 & Remaining current balance\\
Principal proceeds   & \$ & 993,615 & Remaining balance $\times$ \$102-15\\
Accrued Interest & \$ & 1,807 & 12 days of accrued interest\\
Roll in proceeds &  \$ & 995,422 & Roll in proceeds\\
\circled{3}Future Value of principal and carry & \$ & 1,030,333 & Total amount financed\\
\hline

Future value \circled{3} & \$ &  \$1,030,333 &\\
Less Market Value \circled{1} & \$ & \$ 1,030,424 & \\
Implied cost of financing &\$ & -\$91 &\\
\circled{4} \textbf{Implied cost of funds} && -0.106\% &  (-\$91 $\div$ \$ 969,676) $\times$ 100 \\

\end{tabular}

\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please always post a **complete** Minimal Working Example which includes the document class and packages needed to reproduce the issue. Your example should *compile* just by copy-pasting into an editor. In any case, I'm not sure quite what sort of answer you expect. Your tabular is apparently too large so you either need to make it smaller (smaller font, less whitespace, more concise content...) or make the space for it larger (different paper, smaller margins...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `tabularx` package and set your tablewidth to `linewidth`. Here is a way of doing. I also load the `cellspace` package to have a better vertical space between the rows, `caption` to improve spacing between the caption and the table, and `booktabs` to have lines of different thickness. I also suppressed the column dedicated to `$`, replacing it by a convenient intercolumn. If that is not enough, you can ask for a smaller fontsize. Btw, don't use the `center`environment for a table (it adds spurious vertical space) and replace it with `centering`.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand\circled[1]{#1}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{cellspace}
\cellspacetoplimit = 4pt
\cellspacebottomlimit = 4pt
\addparagraphcolumntypes{X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{Implied Cost of Funds}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l @{\qquad\$\:}r @{\qquad}S{X}@{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Beginning Market Value}\\
Principal Proceeds &1,028,437 & $\text{\$1,000,000}  ×  \text{\$102-27}$ \\
Accrued Interest &1,986 & 13 days accrued interest @ 5.50\%\\
\circled{1} \textbf{Market Value} & 1,030,424 & Total proceeds on the "roll out" date \\
\midrule
%
\textbf{Future Value} -- \textit{Pmts. Received}\\
Coupon Income Received & 4,583 & Interest earned @ 5.50\%  based on 30/360\\
Scheduled Principal Received &1,070 & Scheduled principal paid\\
Prepaid Principal Received & 29,254 & Prepaid Principal Received @ 30 CPR\\
Total Payments Received & 34,907 & Expected payments (remittance date)\\
\circled{2} \textbf{Disc. value of the carry} & 34,911
& Present value of the payments received assuming the alternate financing rate (0.31\%)
 and using actual day count (13 days) - act/360 -  on the "roll in" date.\\
\midrule
%
Remaining principal balance & 969,676 & Remaining current balance\\
Principal proceeds   & 993,615 & Remaining balance $ × $ \$102-15\\
Accrued Interest & 1,807 & 12 days of accrued interest\\
Roll in proceeds & 995,422 & Roll in proceeds\\
\circled{3} Future Value of principal and carry & 1,030,333 & Total amount financed\\
\midrule
%
Future value \circled{3} & 1,030,333 \\%
Less Market Value \circled{1} & 1,030,424 \\
Implied cost of financing & -91 \\%
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{\circled{4} \textbf{Implied cost of funds}} &\multicolumn{1}{@{}c@{}}{ -0.106\%} &  (-\$91 $\div$ \$ 969,676) $ × $ 100  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, definitely what I wanted to do but it looks like I must have some conflicts in my other commands and packages.  Looks like Tex built a page for almost every word in the document so I have some research to do for sure.